# BAT-Синтаксис

Tags: bat, cmd

Допустим в батнике:

```
cd C:\Program Files\path\test\  
start someprg.exe
```

Как после выполнения этих команд вернуться обратно в директорию к батнику, где бы он не находился?

Comment: Если вы получаете исчерпывающий ответ - кликайте, пожалуйста, на зелёную галочку рядом с ответом.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

На самом деле оба предложенных решения возвращают запомненную **рабочую директорию**, что не соответствует буквальному условию задачи:

> вернуться обратно в директорию к батнику, где бы он не находился

Сменить директорию на ту, в которой расположен батник, можно так:

```
CD /D A:\SOME\
REM делаем что-либо с относительными путями
CD /D "%~dp0"
```

Comment: @Dexter, затрудняюсь так сразу ответить. Конкретно эта информация - из `CALL /?`. Еще часто заглядываю на сторонний сайт ss64.com. В принципе, считаю тему информации и литературы, нужной для административного скриптинга в NT достойной отдельного вопроса.

Comment: @karmadro4, классный ресурс вы подкинули! Вы системным администратором что ли работаете?

Comment: Если очень интересует работа пакетных файлов в Windows, то рекомендую прочитать две статьи:

 - http://www.rsdn.ru/article/winshell/batanyca.xml
 - http://www.rsdn.ru/article/winshell/NTCommandProcessor.xml

Это лучшие материалы, которые я встречал на великом и могучем.

Ещё пара полезных ресурсов:

 - http://www.robvanderwoude.com/
 - http://commandwindows.com

Comment: @Dexter, @evlanoff, я таки настоятельно рекомендую вынести это в отдельный вопрос, ибо справочники бывают хорошие, бывают плохие, а бывают даже от Майкрософт. Никаких комментариев на них не хватит.

Comment: @evlanoff, исходные ссылки «[умерли](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/580225/%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B5)». Теперь эти статьи доступны только из Wayback Machine: [раз](http://wayback.archive.org/web/20160709100059/http://rsdn.ru/article/winshell/NTCommandProcessor.xml), [два](http://wayback.archive.org/web/20160327021519/http://rsdn.ru/article/winshell/batanyca.xml).

Answer (score 4):

См. help set в cmd

```
set curdir=%cd%
cd c:\ushare
dir
cd %curdir%
```

Что-то в таком духе.

Comment: или открой еще одно CMD а после выполнения программы выйди из него, тогда ты снова будешь где был

Comment: Неплохо, но вариант @karmadro4`а гораздо гибче =)

Answer (score 4):

Иногда может быть полезным воспользоваться командами PUSHD (переход в папку и запоминание старой) и POPD (возврат в запомненную папку)

```
PUSHD папка
REM Что-то полезное делаем
POPD
```

Comment: Так наверняка лучше. 

На .bat (или как там правильно ?) не программирую (в отличие от \*nix Shells). Просто стало интересно, как сделать в windows, вот и посмотрел help в cmd. Что нашел за несколько минут, то и написал.

Comment: Через переменную лучше) 
Объявляешь в начале файла set curdir=%cd%
и используешь cd %curdir% во всем файле)

Answer (score 1):

Лучше всего в данном случае использовать переменные:

```
set up=%cd%
Rem здесь тело батника
cd %up%
```